# Javafx combobox disable dropdown option

Tags: javafx-2

I am using combobox for search option.

--- I need to disable the drop down option in javafx combobox

Comment: Haven't tried it but what happens if you use setVisibleRowCount(int value)
function and set its value to 0? If that doesn't work you'll have to write a custom implementation.

Comment: Why do you want to disable drop down option?